# SQL syntax error Multiple inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2003

```
SELECT *
FROM tproducts
INNER JOIN torder ON tproducts.Product_ID=torder.Product_ID
INNER JOIN tcustomer ON torder.Customer_ID=tcustomer.Customer_ID
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this as VB.net says that there is a missing operator and i cant spot it?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?  What database are you using?

Comment: Have you tried by enclosing each join with parantheses ?

Comment: VB.net --  are you using MS Access? It has unique and finicky requirements for enclosing joins in `()`. Your SQL looks like it would be valid in any other RDBMS as long as the columns exist.

Comment: look like fine till now, include what the error you getting and include vb.net code also where are you calling this?

Comment: I am using MS access 2003

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MS Access, you need to use parentheses for multiple joins:

```
SELECT *
FROM (tproducts INNER JOIN
      torder
      ON tproducts.Product_ID = torder.Product_ID
     ) INNER JOIN
     tcustomer
     ON torder.Customer_ID = tcustomer.Customer_ID;
```

No other database requires this, and using parentheses like this looks awkward for any other database.